What's the best way to implement patterns on graphs to comply with WCAG 2.1 using Angular?
I'm working on a new dashboard on my project, and we need to comply with WCAG 2.1. One of the best ways to do this is using patterns in the graphs for those users with anomalous trichromacy, dichromatic view and monochromatic view. I've been doing some research how to implement these on Angular however as designer I need to check what is the best way to hand-off the patterns.
Do I need to create the svg or use the png is sufficient for the developers?

Awesome that you care about accessibility and to smoothen developer hand-off. But here’s a lot of information missing. Angular is only a web-framework to make interactive web applications. You can implement graphs with it, but it’s all up to the developers. If you use a component library for Angular, there might be constraints and best practices, but we’d need to know the library used.

Also, the WCAG are very large, and there’s a whole bunch of criteria that apply to graphs and data visualisation. Using visual patterns might satisfy Use of Color, but not Non-text Content

Without knowing these details, it’s probably a good idea to find patterns that can be implemented with CSS. They are easy to implement for developers (no matter the library), and they are efficient in use of resources.
